# A problem with Onclick Javascript for this button on link was encountered unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ajax-toolkit

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
Var Ld = new sforce.SObject("Lead"); 
Ld.id = "{!Lead.Id}"; 
Ld.Sent_RFI__c = sforce.connection.update([Ld]); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: looks like some thing is wrong.. `Ld.Sent_RFI__c = sforce.connection.update([Ld]); `  what you want to assign to `Ld.Sent_RFI__c` field?

Comment: I want to assign lead id which has to be given to public URL

Comment: You cannot assign the update of the record to the Field of the same updating record...Please give the question completely with your getting ERROR too....

Comment: A problem with Onclick Javascript for this button on link was encountered unexpected identifier

Comment: The above was the error

Comment: Rashi.. do you want to assign lead Id like this `Ld.Sent_RFI__c =  {!Lead.Id}`.. then you code should be like `{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
Var Ld = new sforce.SObject("Lead"); 
Ld.id = "{!Lead.Id}"; 
Ld.Sent_RFI__c = "{!Lead.Id}"; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([Ld]); 
window.location.reload();`

Answer (score 1):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
var Ld = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
var newRecords = [];
Ld.id = "{!Lead.Id}";
//Give your **Sent RFI** Field with a value over here
newRecords.push(Ld);
var result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

Try This One...
Hope this Helps